# Is there a way to control label density in mapserver?

Tags: mapserver

I'm reading a US County Tiger Shapefile and everything is plotting correctly, but I want to slim down the number of labels shown at scales larger than the state level because it begins to overwhelm the map.  Is there a way to modify this to do that, but leave the zoomed in look and feel alone?

```
LAYER
NAME 'us_counties'
TYPE POLYGON
DUMP true
TEMPLATE fooOnlyForWMSGetFeatureInfo  
DATA './shapefiles/uscounties_20130327.shp'
METADATA
  'ows_title' 'counties_us'
END    
PROCESSING "LABEL_NO_CLIP=True"

PROJECTION
  'proj=longlat'
  'ellps=GRS80'
  'datum=NAD83'
  'no_defs'
END

LABELITEM 'NAME'
CLASS
  NAME 'uscounties_20130327' 
  STYLE
    WIDTH 0.91 
    OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    #COLOR 108 180 98
  END
  LABEL 
  FONT verabd
  TYPE truetype
  SIZE 12
  COLOR 0 0 0
  OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
  ANGLE 0
  POSITION cc
  FORCE true
  ANTIALIAS true
  PARTIALS false
END 
END
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MINDISTANCE command to specify the minimum amount of pixels per label. MINDISTANCE works with duplicate labels

MINFEATURESIZE is also another good choice if you have a wide range of object sizes in  your dataset. This will allow you to set which features are labeled based on their screen size.